# Adding a Spark node to clusters gets stuck on Determining SSH fingerprints

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am trying to add a new Spark node to an existing DSE 4.8.4 cluster running on EC2. I use following settings:

- AMI = ami-50520e27
- AMI username = ubuntu
- Use OpsCenter specific security group
- Key file using by the existing cluster

The machine spins up, but in OpsCenter > Activities > Add Nodes there is a message saying "Determining SSH fingerprints" which stays there forever.

Comment: Does your vpc automatically assign external IP addresses?

Comment: I don't seem to have any VPC

Comment: In order to spin up nodes you must have a vpc even if it's the default vpc which does auto assign public IP's http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/default-vpc.html

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue now?

Comment: Don't know but I've seen the symptoms you're describing when the amazon VPC doesn't have a public IP set up for the node.

Comment: I have checked it, and auto assign is enabled for the VPC.

Comment: The Add node is stuck with the following error -> Fingerprint Detection failed: The following IPs didn't return keys: